# I want to return ul li from file get contents

Tags: php

I have one txt file and i want to rutern in php file in ul,li how i can do this?

test.txt =>

```
line1.
line2.
```

index.php =>

```
$txtfile=file_get_contents("test.txt");

<ul>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($list2) ?>
<ul>
```

but i want this:

```
<li>line1.</li>
<li>line2.</li>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it with `array_walk` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php with less code

```
$lines=file('test.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
array_walk($lines,function (&$i){
       // you can all your htmlspecialchars or any modification needed here function here
       $i="<li>$i</li>"; 
    });
print_r ($lines);
```

Edit: The above code parses and stores the result in an array. If you just want to echo you can try this.

```
//get all the lines in an array without the newline chars at end of each line
$lines=file('test.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
array_walk($lines,function ($i){
    echo"<li>$i</li>";// echo each line with prefix and suffix.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Open file handle 
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

echo "<ul>";

try {
    // While end of file not reached ->
    while (!feof($file)) {
        // Get next row from file and convert special characters to HTML entities
        echo "<li>" . htmlspecialchars(fgets($file)) . "</li>";
    }
} finally {
    // Close pointer to file
    fclose($file);
}

echo "</ul>";
```

This will iterate through all the lines in file and add them to the elements of the list.

Comment: Nice decoration - all these curly braces and cool words around.

Comment: @petrosvel why so much concern for mere a decoration?

Comment: I see. It seems I confused programmers resource with art gallery